# Why does unity's top panel stop to respond after some time after login (i.e. grabbing, double and middle clicking on it stops to work)

Tags: unity, panel

I tried to report a bug but ubuntu-bug directed me here so here we go:

I recently installed Natty (new install with an old /home partition) and started to use Unity (have not used it before). Unity works fine for me except the fact that after some time, top panel stops responding to grabbing and double and middle clicking. The time it takes to stop responding varies and I have not been able to figure out what triggers it.

Global menu works, as well as indicators and launcher, I can acces the top panel with F10. I am not even sure it is a Unity and not a compiz bug. Has anyone encoutered this? Have you any idea if something in my configuration might be using it? Right after logon, the panel works as expected.

Comment: I have seen similer things on my nvidia based system, the top bar will be totally black, but in my case everything seems to work Its just a solid black bar. I Did notice once that some inticator-applet icons reappeared but the rest of the bar was solid black.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen panel as a black (or colored occaisonally) box too - but grabbing the panel and so on worked (I think). 

But what I am describing is visiually absolutely perfect panel that does not respond to grabing and middle clicking.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/781865 - corresponding bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/774121) and has been fixed.